# Why is np.average, among other average calculators, giving this result

Tags: python, numpy

Can someone explain to my why, according to many average calculators, the average of this array is some very small negative number instead of zero?

> [-5.4, -4.4, -2.4, -1.4, 13.6]

for example, numpy.average and numpy.mean return this value:

```
-3.5527136788e-16
```

Comment: Floating-point numbers are not precise.

Comment: A very good answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Answer (score 0):

Because float numerics is not perfect. And simply this does not sum to 0, but to something around 1e-14 in this system. You can find even more funny things - change order of your numbers and then calculate sum/mean and you will find that result depends on ordering too. The short story is that you cannot express 0.4 nor 0.6 in base 2, which is used in computers.